# Un-Share Session Cookies of webbrowser control

Tags: c#, http-headers, webbrowser-control

I have more than one webbrowser controls on my program, and it seams they all share session cookies.
What i want is that they DONT share the session cookies.

I have different webbrowser controls that opens the same website with different accounts, or open the same web-page that store different data in session.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebBrowser control is essentially an instance of Internet Explorer's renderer and HTTP logic, including cookie and session handling. The cookies are stored in the standard IE cookie directory.

You'll have to switch to HttpWebRequest or WebClient if you want to manually handle cookies.

Comment: Just do a Google search for `c# WebClient example` or `c# HttpWebRequest example`, you'll find a whole pile of sample code and articles on the issue. They won't allow you to directly render the pages, but you'll be able to do HTTP GET/POST requests and access the results as a stream or string.