# Un-Share Session or Cookies of webbrowser control in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webkit, webbrowser-control, session-cookies

I have more than one webbrowser controls on my program, and it seams they all share session cookies.
What i want is that they DONT share the session cookies.

I have different webbrowser controls that opens the same website with different accounts, or open the same web-page that store different data in session.

Anyone has any idea?

Note : this question already posted by @Haroldis,[Link old quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969630/un-share-session-cookies-of-webbrowser-control?s=d893a32f-9b66-416c-8a29-ea23813de18c#new-answer) Hope now he found the solution already because I having this problem also.

Comment: @Haroldis , Please help if you can be done this problem , share code to me Please .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer you linked, this is not possible with the standard .net web browser control.
IF you genuinely need to display the pages in browsers to the user (rather than just send or recieve data, in which case webrequests are your answer) then you have a few options via third party software.

1 would be WaTin, which allows you to launch and control separate browser instances, with the option of not sharing cookies.

Another option would be awesomium, which has a .net wrapper and can run independent instances since v1.7, though i have not tested it a great deal.

Comment: Yes i tested with it already, it still overwrite session while i login multiple user, i don't know that because i wrote code wrong or not......but for awesomium still shared session,
if you have some code to show me as example, please share
thank in advanced